# How to send JSON data using rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-3

Hi I am trying to create a custom controller that return a method as json.

Here my controller

```
respond_to :json
  def rates
    @event = Event.find(params[:id])
    respond_with @event.avg_rating
  end
```

Now I have my model with the following method

```
# returns the average rating for that event
def avg_rating
  @avg = self.ratings.average(:stars)     
  @avg ? @avg : 0
end
```

However when i get the respond I get this:

```
3.75
```

What I would like is a standard json respond either `{"event": "3.75"}`

But I am not sure what to use to simply transform it to make an answer like that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need an actual object to be rendered to json. A hash is usually easiest. And you will want to use render instead of respond_with

```
    render json: {:event => @event.avg_rating}
```

Comment: Thank you, simple and what i am looking for, will accept answer once allowed